# Font isn't changing from CSS FIles

Tags: html, css

Currently using Django with bootstrap 4. For whatever reason, I cannot get the font-family to change through my main.css file. I can change other attributes, but font does not seem to work.

If I change the font-family in my other files, it works. I just cannot change it through my main.css.

What am I doing wrong?

index.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
...
```

main.css

```css
body {
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you looked at the generated HTML to make sure it is correct? Have you checked the Network tab to make sure the main.css file is loading? And that it contains the content you expect (and not, for example, some old, cached content)? Have you used the DOM inspector to look at the body element to see if the CSS is applied to it? And that it isn't being overridden by another rule that applies to the same element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have 2 options, create a style tag in the head tag or select everything instead of body in main.css. Example:

index.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;
        }
    </style>
...
```

or

main.css

```css
* {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Why would that help? The OP said that it worked if the code was in a different file.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is overriding the css even with the !important tag. If you do inline styling it should override bootstrap.
`<body style='font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;'>`